# Template type of class in inheritance

Tags: c++, templates

Let's say I have class **Action**

```
template<class T>
class Action {
public:
    virtual ~Action() = default;

    virtual void execute(T &object) const = 0;
};
```

which can be executed on some object of type **T**

Next, I have class **Object**

```
class Object {
public:
    Object() : actions() {}

    virtual ~Object() = default;

    virtual const std::string getName() const = 0;

    void addAction(const Action<Object> *action) {
        actions.push_back(action);
    }

    void execute() {
        for (auto &action : actions) {
            action->execute(*this);
        }
    }

private:
    std::vector<const Action<Object> *> actions;
};
```

which holds a vector of actions which can be executed at once.

Now, I have some concrete **ObjectA**

```
class ObjectA : public Object {
public:
    const std::string getName() const override {
        return "ObjectA";
    }
};
```

and two concrete actions **ActionA**, **ActionB**

```
class ActionA : public Action<ObjectA> {
    void execute(ObjectA &object) const override {
        std::cout << "ActionA on " << object.getName() << std::endl;
    }
};

class ActionB : public Action<ObjectA> {
    void execute(ObjectA &object) const override {
        std::cout << "ActionB on " << object.getName() << std::endl;
    }
};
```

The usage is that I create an ObjectA, add both action to it and execute them.

```
int main() {
    ObjectA object = ObjectA{};

    object.addAction(reinterpret_cast<const Action<Object> *>(new ActionA()));
    object.addAction(reinterpret_cast<const Action<Object> *>(new ActionB()));

    // This is what I want to achieve instead of using reinterpret_cast
    //object.addAction(new ActionA());
    //object.addAction(new ActionB());

    object.execute();
}
```

The output should be

```
ActionA on ObjectA
ActionB on ObjectA
```

The problem is that in order to compile it, I must use `reinterpret_cast`. The problem is probably the definition of `std::vector<const Action<Object> *> actions;` I would like to template this, so in `ObjectA` it is like `std::vector<const Action<ObjectA> *> actions;`

Is something like that possible?

Comment: `std::vector<const Action<Object> *> actions` -> `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<const Action<Object>>> actions` or `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Action<Object>>> actions`

Comment: Your `Action` looks a lot like `std::function<void(T&)>`

Comment: I don't see `DerivedA` appear anywhere in the code given.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it.

Comment: An `ActionA` is-a `Action<ObjectA>`.  An `Action<ObjectA>` is-not-a `Action<Object>`.

Comment: I think the problem is that there is a bit of a tangled mess between compile-time polymorphism, conflated with runtime (virtual function table) polymorphism.  Pick one.  Don't try to mix-and-match them, because they don't always play nice together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Action<Object>` and `Action<ObjectA>` are unrelated types in the C++ type system.

What more, `Action<Object>` permits itself to be called with *more types* than `Action<ObjectA>`.  So ignoring the type system, an `Action<ObjectA>` cannot implement the contract that `Action<Object>` promises it can fulfill.

However, an `Action<Object>` *can* fulfill the promise that an `Action<ObjectA>` makes.

There are famous two kinds of OO-type relations; covariance and contravariance.  `Action<T>` is cotravariant in `T`, `Action<Base>` can be used to fulfill the contract of `Action<Derived>`.

---

So an approach.

First, your `Action<T>` is a poorly written pointer-semantic version of `std::function<void(T&)>`.  Use that instead.

You now have value semantics.

```
template<class T>
using Action=std::function<void(T&)>;

class Object {
public:
    Object() = default;

    virtual ~Object() = default;

    virtual const std::string getName() const = 0;

    void addAction(Action<Object> action) {
        actions.emplace_back(std::move(action));
    }

    void execute() {
        for (auto &action : actions) {
            action(*this);
        }
    }

private:
    std::vector<Action<Object>> actions;
};
```

ah, much nicer.

This doesn't, however, solve your problem.

```
auto ActionA = Action<ObjectA>{
  [](ObjectA &object) {
    std::cout << "ActionA on " << object.getName() << std::endl;
  }
};
```

`ActionA` cannot be assigned to an `Action<Object>` because an `Action<Object>` can be passed a non-`ObjectA` and it must *do something* with it.

Your original code's `override` won't compile.

We have to decide if we want to pretend to be an `Action<Object>` what we should do if the types mismatch?  Here is one option:

```
template<class T, class F>
auto only_when_dynamic_type_matches( F&& f ) {
  if constexpr( std::is_pointer< T >{} ) {
    return
      [f=std::forward<F>(f)](auto* x)->void{
        auto* t = dynamic_cast<T>(x);
        if (!t) return
        f(t);
      };
  } else {
    return
      [f=std::forward<F>(f)](auto&& x)->void{
        auto* t = dynamic_cast<std::remove_reference_t<T>*>(std::addressof(x));
        if (!t) return;
        f(*t);
      };
  }
}
```

now we can write

```
auto ActionA = only_when_dynamic_type_matches<ObjectA&>([](auto&&object) {
  std::cout << "ActionA on " << object.getName() << std::endl;
});
auto ActionB = only_when_dynamic_type_matches<ObjectA&>([](auto&&object) {
  std::cout << "ActionB on " << object.getName() << std::endl;
});
```

then

```
int main() {
    ObjectA object = ObjectA{};

    object.addAction(ActionA);
    object.addAction(ActionB);

    object.execute();
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fbe86397d8ed5114).

Comment: Thanks for you answer. It works. The reason I defined my own `Action<T>` is because I will need to extend it in the future, for example by adding `virtual void validate(T &object) const = 0;` or some parameter would be used during action execution. Is it possible to use `Action<T>` class and improve it instead of using `std::function<void(T&)>`?

Comment: @AdamDohnal Yes, `std::function` can be implemented by a user.  It is not trivial.  I used `std::function` to permit extending the restricted version to a more general version; doing so for `Action<T>` would require roughly as much work as writing your own `std::function`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will use `std::function` and alter my design.